# How to display the php values into html table?

Tags: php, html

I have almost did the displaying of values.But i am getting an extra td  I hope the complete code is right.
Can anyone see it once.

**php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hoteldetails');
    $sno[]="";
    $roomImage[]="";
    $roomNo[] = "";
    $hotelName[]="";
    $roomPrice[]="";
    $loc[]="";
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        // mysqli_s(elect_db($link, "hotels");
        $location=$_POST['searchVal'];
        $sql = "select * from roomdetails where Location = '$location'";
        $sqldata= mysqli_query($link ,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){

            $sno[]=$row['S.No'];
            $roomImage[] = $row['RoomImage'];
            $roomNo[] = $row['RoomNo'];
            $hotelName[] = $row['HotelName'];
            $roomPrice[] = $row['RoomPrice'];
            $loc[] = $row['Location'];
        }
       //two arrays to display ,$combine = array_combine($one,$two);
    }


    ?>
```

**html**

```
<?php 
         echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Hotel</th><th>Location</th></tr>";


                        foreach($sno as $id => $key):

                           echo "<tr>";
                             echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $roomImage[$id];?>" height="100" width="100"><?php echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$roomNo[$id]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$hotelName[$id]."</td>";
                           echo "<td>".$roomPrice[$id]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$loc[$id]."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";

                        endforeach;
                        echo "</table>";

                        //echo $html;
                            ?>
```

Is there anything wrong in it . Please is this process is right to display the values from mysql into html.

Comment: *"Is there anything wrong in it . Please is this process is right to display the values from mysql into html."* - You should be telling us that.

Comment: I got the output what i need. But the thing is i am getting an extra td at the beginning.

Comment: Your table header row has two columns and other rows 5 columns..

Comment: which is what you coded for.

Comment: Actually i dnt need any headers Leave about the headers. even if it is in comment line, the extra td at beginning is displayed with all the empty values

Answer (score 0):

First, format your code, using tools like http://phpbeautifier.com for example.

Next, you have lines that contain both an `echo` and a `?> ... <?php` instruction that tells php to `echo` stuff without any PHP parsing.
This is quite unreadable and unmaintainable.

You should better go for some "templating-like" practices using only HTML and using PHP only to output some vars, like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $item) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: <?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
        <td>Price: <?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

This would drastically improve readability, maintainability, and especially your capacity of debugging the code.

And finally, you should take care of your `php.ini` configuration and check that `display_errors` is set to `1` and `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`.
This way, any error like `PHP - Notice : Undefined index ...` will be shown in the output so you can debug it.